# How do I calculate acreage grouped by owner, masked by a poly?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, measurements, masking

I have statewide land ownership data and have created a mask to project ownership for only one county.  I need to calculate the acreage of each owner within that county.  Is there a quick way to achieve this?  I'm using ArcGIS 10.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'Calculate Geometry' (Right click on an field in the attribute table) tool to determine the area of each polygon and then use the 'Summary Statistics' (in the Analysis toolbox) with the owner name as a Case field and the area field set to sum will produce a table that shows the total area for every unique entry in the owner name field.

[Here is the link to the help file for the summary statistics tool.](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Summary%20Statistics%20%28Analysis%29)

Limiting the results to one county can be accomplished through a variety of ways.  The most straightforward one is to use the county layer to clip out all the shapes from the ownership polygon for just that polygon.  [You could also use the polygon shapefile as an analysis environment in the workspace of your document](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005900000019000000) (provided you have access to a license of spatial analyst)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I'll give this a try tomorrow and let you know how it turns out. ~D'

Answer (score 1):

Create a field in the attribute table to store the acreages.  Do a select by location query that intersects the parcels with your mask.  In the attribute table right click on the name of your new field and use the Geometry Calculator.  You can select acreage from there.

You'll need to specify a projection, hopefully your data is in UTM or State Plane.

This YouTube video can walk you through the process:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fr5bB4rMs-o

Comment: Thanks, I wish it were that easy, and I appreciate the link to the video.  However, @KevinV is on the right track so I'll try his suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: No worries.  I missed the fact that you need to group by owner.  Another way to handle it would be to after you calculate the individual parcel acreages export your attribute table to Excel, import the Excel file to Access and run your query there.  Xtools Pro can handle the export, the export to Excel function is free even after your evaluation period runs out.  http://www.dataeast.com/en/XToolspro.asp